# django migrate "No migrations to apply."

Tags: python, django, migration, database-migration

I kind of know why when I do `migrate` it gives me the message of `no migrations to apply` but I just don't know how to fix it

This is what happens.

I added a new field named `update` into my model fields.
I did a `migration` which created a file called `0003_xxxxx.py` then I did a `migrate` now this worked fine.

But then because of some reason, I have to remove the `update` field from the same model.
So I removed it (more likey commented instead of really delete the code) then I did `migration` and `migrate` which removed the field in db. (created `0004_xxxxx.py`)

But sigh....some reason I have to add the field back again (this is why I only commented out) but then before I do the `migration`
I removed the `0003_xxxx.py and 0004_xxxx.py` files I wanted to remove those two files because this is actually the same or almost the same config as `0003_xxxx.py` so I feel it's pointless having the `0003_xxxx.py and 0004_xxxx.py` here...also when I go production, that's just another extra step for python to run.

After I removed those two files, I did the `migration` which creates another `0003_xxxx.py` but when I do `migrate` it gives me the message of `no migrations to apply`

I know that by deleting the `0003_xxxx.py` and get the original `0003 and 0004` back then do another `migration (creates 0005_xxxx.py) then migrate`  then changes will be made.  I know this because I didn't really delete the original `0003 and 0004` I moved it somewhere just in case of this kind of happening.

But why is this though? and is there a way to fix it?

Thanks in advance for any replies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

django keep records of current `migrations` log by table `django_migrations` in your db.

something like:
[image]

The migrations is a chain structure,it's depend on the parent node.By this table django can know which migrations file is executed.

In you case,`no migrations to apply` because the new create `0003_xxxx.py` is record in this table,you can fix it by delete this record in this table.

If you want remove some migration file you need see [Squashing migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations).

Comment: So this means, I need to run the squashing command like..`manage.py squashmigrations myapp 0003` ? then run the `migration` again to create a new `0003` in order to `migrate` properly?

Comment: before that you need delete record 003 004 in table django_migrations

Comment: darn that means the id in db will not be sequencial and gone...but ended up I remove them in the `django_migrations` I didn't need to do `sqashmigrations` and it still works though because I tried to use `squashmigrations app_name 0003` it says no migrations match

Comment: sqashmigrations is used when you want set many migrations files to one,it;s not something must be done.

Comment: which means if one say there are like 100 migration files created, I can `sqashmigrations` them into one file `0001.py`

Comment: Yes,that's what `sqashmigrations` does.

Answer (score 1):

Or even simply just delete the last migration row from your database you can try the following

First, check which row you want to remove

```
SELECT * FROM "public"."django_migrations";
```

Now pick the last `id` from the above query and execute

```
DELETE FROM "public"."django_migrations" WHERE "id"=replace with your Id;
```

run `./manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

just run:

```
python manage.py run --run-syncdb
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything only gives an error: Unknown command: 'run'